# I am getting an error Subscript Out of Range in Excel 2010

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub RunCompare()

Call compareSheets("Latest", "SFDC")

End Sub

Sub compareSheets(shtLatest As String, shtSFDC As String)

Dim mycell As Range
Dim mydiffs As Integer

'For each cell in sheet2 that is not the same in Sheet1, color it yellow
For Each mycell In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSFDC).UsedRange
    If Not mycell.Value = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtLatest).Cells(mycell.Row, mycell.Column).Value Then

        mycell.Interior.Color = vbYellow
        mydiffs = mydiffs + 1

    End If
Next

'Display a message box to demonstrate the differences
MsgBox mydiffs & " differences found", vbInformation
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(SFDC).Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm really sorry for that but...where you get the error? which line? did you use any debugging technique (like F8 key)?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub RunCompare()

    compareSheets "Latest", "SFDC"

End Sub

'Compares two sheets and colours yellow any cell in sheet2 that is not the same as in sheet 1
Sub compareSheets(sheet1 As String, sheet2 As String)

    Dim rCell1 As Range
    Dim rCell2 As Range
    Dim nDiffs As Long ' Using a long because Integer may one day be too small

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet

    Set ws1 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet1)
    Set ws2 = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(sheet2)

    For Each rCell1 In ws1.UsedRange.Cells
        Set rCell2 = ws2.Range(rCell1.Address)
        If rCell1.Value <> rCell2.Value Then
            rCell2.Interior.Color = vbYellow
            nDiffs = nDiffs + 1
        End If
    Next rCell1

    Debug.Print nDiffs

End Sub
```

This should help you produce a workable solution. In your code, the 'For Each mycell' line creates a loop on each 'Range' object in 'UsedRange' not on each individual cell.

Comment: Note that this will fail to colour any cells in sheet2 that are outside of the UsedRange of sheet1.

Answer (score 0):

Your 'Subscript out of range' may become from invalid sheet names.

Are you sure that active book when you call macro is one with <kbd>Latest</kbd> and <kbd>SFDC</kbd> worksheets.

Not directly related to problem, but I would suggest you to change your function prototype to

```
Sub compareSheets(ByVal shtLatest As Worksheet, ByVal shtSFDC As Worksheet)
```

replace all `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(shtSFDC)` with `shtSFDC` (same for `shtLatest`) and finally replace call with

```
Call compareSheets(ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Latest"), ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SFDC"))
```

or directly with code name:

```
Call compareSheets(sheet1, sheet2)
```

That is clearer as `compareSheets` expects sheets, not text.